# Confused about the resolution for IOS 6+ devices

Tags: icon, resolution, ios, slices

I had designed one app for IPhone 5 and 6 and now I want to make the same app design for IPhone 6+ so what can be the resolution of its assets?

### **Currently I had done following things in Photoshop.**

- IPhone 5 or less: Icon Size= 55X55 (x)
- IPhone 6: Icon Size= 110X110 (2x)
- IPhone 6+: Icon Size= 165X165 (3x)

Still I am facing problem is slicing.
Is is correct resolution? or what is the correct way to slice for IOS 6+ Devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your asset is 55 pixels for the 1× size, then you'll be after 110 for 2× and 165 for 3×.

The iPhone 6 Plus should be treated as a full 3× UI scale device. You should use a 1242 × 2208px canvas when designing a full screen mockup. This is because the iPhone 6 Plus renders internally to a larger virtual canvas, then bitmap scales the entire screen down to 1080 × 1920px.

iPhone 6 Screens Demystified:
http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

It’s easier to build and consider sizes to be in iOS points. Here’s the various iPhone models, with the screen dimensions in points:

[image: iPhone display sizes in points]

And I've written a bit about my workflow here: http://bjango.com/articles/appdesignworkflow/

Comment: Hey Marc, Maybe you could clarify. For example, If I'd design on 1242x2208, And I have a resource 1242x1242 (a cube on the screen) - How would I slice it to @2x and @1x? ... Should I resize my canvas to 828x1472 so the math makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to read Apple's Human Interface guidelines for iOS. This page in particular might have what you need:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html